# How to Minimize Skype to Windows 7 System Tray (Notification Area)

Tags: windows-7, skype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get Skype to not stay minimized in the task bar?](https://superuser.com/questions/130789/how-can-i-get-skype-to-not-stay-minimized-in-the-task-bar)

Due to the new design behavior guideline for Windows Taskbar on Windows 7, more and more software application has now making its icon to locate and stick at Windows 7 Taskbar when minimized, instead of minimizing to system tray (notification area).

How do I prevent this for Skype?

Comment: Actually this is not a duplicate: the solution offered to the other question removes Skype from the taskbar, but it does not appear in the system tray either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a very good answer with pictures I found over at [My Digital Life](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2010/01/23/how-to-minimize-skype-to-windows-7-system-tray-notification-area/).

In short.
 1. Uncheck the ["Advanced"] option "*Keep Skype in the taskbar while I’m signed in*"
 2. Run skype in *Vista SP2 compability mode*